# Please explain this weird Javascript line

Tags: javascript, syntax, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I came across a piece of code that is:

```
for(i=((90.0E1,0x5A)<=(0x158,140.70E1)?(.28,3.45E2,0):(95.30E1,26.40E1)<=1.400E2?(1,this):(108.,0x227));i<length;i++) { 
   // some other code here
}
```

Can someone help me by explaining the stuff in the for() brackets?

Comment: I hope you didn't come across this filth in proper code!

Comment: Obfuscation provided by this site https://jscrambler.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Comma_Operator) is always the value to the right hand side.
So each pair of the form (a,b) evaluates to b. Since in your code "a" never has a side effect, we can 
simply omit it to get:

```
for(i=(0x5A <= 140.70E1 ? 0 : ...);i<length;i++) {
```

Where "..." stands for stuff that doesn't matter:
Since 0x5A <= 140.70E1 evaluates to `true`, the result of the [?:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator is the value to the right of the question mark, i.e. 0.

So the result is equivalent to

```
 for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
```

which makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

It is a standard three-expression `for` statement, where the first expression, the initializer, happens to be defined as

```
i = ((90.0E1,0x5A)<=(0x158,140.70E1)?(.28,3.45E2,0):(95.30E1,26.40E1)<=1.400E2?(1,this):(108.,0x227))
```

In this expression, the ternary [`?:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) operator, and, to complicate things, does this in a nested fashion.

The syntax of the `?:` operator is the following

```
condition ? value if true : value if false
```

Given this, the expression is composed of the following

```
condition:      (90.0E1,0x5A)<=(0x158,140.70E1)
value if true:  (.28,3.45E2,0)
value if false: (95.30E1,26.40E1)<=1.400E2?(1,this):(108.,0x227)
```

The value-if-false holds a nested expression using the `?:` operator which can of course be deconstructed in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying the hex and E numbers, it becomes:

```
for(i=((900,90)<=(344,1407)?(.28,345,0):(953,264)<=140?(1,this):(108.,551));i<length;i++)

((900,90)<=(344,1407)?(.28,345,0):(953,264)<=140?(1,this):(108.,551)) == 0;
```

which makes the code equivalent to:

```
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
```

It's a very creative and confusing way to make a `for` loop, and a good joke.